# How to disable or auto-select 'OK' on VBA dialogs using Python (Application.DisplayAlerts = False does not work)

Tags: excel, vba, python-3.x, pywin32, win32com

I have a script that opens an Excel spreadsheet and then goes to a specific sheet before running a macro. The problem is that this macro brings up different dialog boxes which require user input - I am trying to automate the process. I have tried to get rid of these boxes by using the following code:

```
import os
impor win32com.client

xl = win32com.client.Dispatch('Excel.Application')
xl = DisplayAlerts = False #Supposed to disable alert/messages/dialog boxes
wb = xl.Workbooks.Open(os.path.abspath('Test.xlsm'), ReadOnly = 0) #Opens spreadsheet
wb.Worksheets('Assets').Activate() #Activates correct sheet
wb.Application.Run('MxRunAction') #Runs macro
wb.Clost(True)
```

I have read on many threads that:

> Application.DisplayAlerts = False

is supposed to fix this problem, yet this seems to do nothing if I substitue **Application** with **xl** for my case. Am I using it properly in this sense?

Comment: I don't know a thing about Python, but in VBA it would be `Application.DisplayAlerts = False` ... So, wouldn't that translate to `xl.DisplayAlerts = False` instead of `xl = ...`?

Comment: That's what I have tried using but it doesn't seem to do anything to the message boxes.

Comment: If the code explicitly pops up a messagebox (or some other dialog) then `DisplayAlerts` (or any other setting) isn't going to change that behavior...

Comment: The macro that runs is password protected and unfortunately I can't change it. Is there something I can write that could auto-select the options?

Comment: Likely you would need some Windows API calls in order to locate and click the desired button(s).  That will not be super-simple...

Answer (score 1):

That would be the Application need to be closed

```
xl.DisplayAlerts = False
```